# trouble inserting data into a SET in c++

Tags: c++, struct, set

```
struct XY {
    float x;
    float y;
}

struct coor {
    XY p, q, r, s;
    string type;
    int pageNo;
    friend bool operator<(coor const& m, coor const& n)
    {
        return ((m.pageNo == n.pageNo)&& (m.p.y < n.p.y)) || ((m.pageNo == n.pageNo) && ((m.p.y == n.p.y) && (m.p.x < n.p.x)))
            || ((m.pageNo != n.pageNo)&& (m.p.y < n.p.y)) || ((m.pageNo != n.pageNo) && ((m.p.y == n.p.y) && (m.p.x < n.p.x)));
    }
};

set<coor>inputs;
```

[image]

---

sample data:

## x1 y1 x2 y2 pageNo type

[image: sampleData]

I want to insert all this data into a SET shown above.
but when i run the program SET gets only this data not all-
[image]

I want all the data ordered by pageNo in ascending order.

---

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong? 
TIA

Comment: Pictures are painful. You could supply the data in a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). and a few lines of main console code to make it easier. But, copy this and look: You have difficult and hard to maintain compactor  if((m.pageNo != n.pageNo)
  return m.pageNo < n.pageNo
 if(m.p.y != n.p.y>
  return m.p.y < n.p.y;
 if(m.p.x != n.p.x)
  return m.p.x < n.p.x;

Comment: You can supply `set` with a custom compare function. ie compare based on `pageNo`.

Comment: That `operator <` could probably be written simply as `return std::tie(m.pageNo, m.x, m.y) < std::tie(n.PageNo, m.x, m.y);`  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie I learned something.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you so much man. :) it works perfectly.

Comment: Correction, that should be `return std::tie(m.pageNo, m.x, m.y) < std::tie(n.PageNo, n.x, n.y);`.  If this works correctly, I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `operator <` is overly complex, and I didn't check if it follows a strict weak ordering.

Having said that, the `operator <` could be rewritten to do a lexicographical comparison using tuples by utilizing `std::tie`:

```
#include <tuple>
//…
friend bool operator<(coor const& m, coor const& n)
{
   return std::tie(m.pageNo, m.p.x, m.p.y) <  std::tie(n.pageNo, n.p.x, n.p.y)
}
```

This will first compare the pageNo, then the `x`, and then the `y` members.  This will guarantee that there is a strict weak ordering for the `std::set` for the data.

Note that there should be enough components to test to guarantee uniqueness if you want to place all the items in a `std::set`.  If the comparison needs to go deeper than just these 3 items, just expand `std::tie` to include a test for the new components.